# Timebase Ground-Loops - why place the isolation transformer at the input instead of the output?

Tags: isolation, ground-loop, frequency-measurement, coax

In the course of investigating the construction of a home-made 10 MHz lab frequency reference I wondered if the output from such a reference should be isolated. I came across a small article about this in an issue of [Hewlett Packard Bench Briefs (1st Quarter 1995, page 2-3)](http://hparchive.com/Bench_Briefs/HP-Bench-Briefs-1995-01-03.pdf) where the author had a problem with ground loops due to the shared connection to his "house frequency standard". Here is a quote from the article and a retouched copy of the illustration showing the problem and the solution:

> #### The Solution
>
> Break the timebase ground-loop by inserting isolation transformers between the frequency distribution amplifier and the external timebase input of each instrument. (Place each isolation transformer as near the external timebase input as possible.)
> [image: Solving a timebase ground-loop]
> <sup>**Figure 1. Block diagram showing simplified ground-loop problem**</sup>

The author is carefully telling us that the isolation should happen at the *input* to each device, both by writing so explicitly and by pointing to them in the diagram.

Why is the position of the isolation transformer so important here? What is the difference when placing it at the output of the distribution amplifier?

Answer (score 1):

A load impedance—the isolation transformer in this case—should always be connected at the end of a transmission line, not at the line's beginning. This is related to transmission line theory (signal reflections, etc.).

I noticed that the Mini-Circuits isolation transformer mentioned in the article has a characteristic impedance of 75 Ω. Considering that Mini-Circuits also makes a 50 Ω isolation transformer (note 1), I'm wondering if perhaps the DISTRIBUTION AMPLIFIER (DA) mentioned in the article has a 75 Ω output impedance, and 75 Ω coaxial cables were used to connect the DA's output signal to the isolation transformer.

If I recall correctly, the EXT REF IN inputs (which the author labels as EXT TB IN) on the 3325B and 3585B required a 10 MHz signal (or a subharmonic down to 1 MHz) terminated into 50 Ω. *(NB: I don't recall the input impedance of the EXT REF IN jacks, so I'm not sure if an external 50 Ω feed-thru termination is required or not.)* Assuming I'm correct about the DA being a 75 Ω system, I would also insert a 75/50 matching pad (impedance converter) between each isolation transformer (IT) and the EXT REF IN input on the 3325B and 3585B.

```
[DA]--75-ohm coax-->[(bal)IT(unbal)]-->[75/50 pad]-->[50-ohm feed-thru term?]-->[(EXT REF IN) 3325B]
```

---

NOTE 1) FTB-1-1*A15+ BNC(F,F) or FTP-1-1*C15+ BNC(M,F)